# Finding a 2SAT instance that has a specific solution set

Tags: satisfiability, counting, 2-sat

Is there a 2SAT instance of variables $(a,b,c,d,e,f,g)$ that has exactly the solution set $S=\{ (1,0,0,0,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0,0,0,0),(0,0,1,0,0,0,0),(1,1,0,1,0,0,0),(1,0,1,0,1,0,0),(0,1,1,0,0,1,0),(1,1,1,1,1,1,1) \}$? It sounds plausible, but other than enumeration, I can't seem to find a way to prove/disprove that it exists.

Comment: What's wrong with enumeration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me teach you a systematic way to answer this type of question.

First, write a program to enumerate over all possible clauses, test for each whether it is satisfied by every assignment in $S$, and keep the ones that are satisfied.  There are only $O(n^2)$ possible clauses, where $n$ is the number of variables, so this is feasible.

Next, create a formula $\varphi$ by taking the conjunction of all of those clauses.  By construction, every assignment in $S$ is satisfied by $\varphi$.  Test whether there is any other satisfying assignment to $\varphi$.  If there is, the answer is that there is no formula whose solution set is exactly $S$.  If there is not, then you have found that there is such a formula, and $\varphi$ is one such.

Since this is your exercise, I will let you write out the details of the proof for why this algorithm works, and how to test whether there is any other satisfying assignment to $\varphi$ (see, e.g., [Finding all solutions if you can find one](https://escholarship.org/content/qt04z1t9gk/qt04z1t9gk.pdf), Rina Dechter and Alon Itai, UC Irvine tech report, 1992-09-16; or [Network Flow and 2-Satisfiability](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01240738.pdf), Feder, Algorithmica 1994, vol 11, pp.291--319, Section 8; or just use a SAT solver).

Comment: Thanks --- I can immediately see that my question is answered in the negative because there is no clause which is satisfied by every assignment in $S$!

Answer (score 1):

Let $\varphi$ a 2CNF with $S$ as solution set.

- Since $(1,1,1,1,1,1,1)$ satisfies $\varphi$, each clause must contain a positive litteral.
- Since $(1,0,0,0,0,0,0)$ satisfies $\varphi$, each clause must contain either a negative litteral $\neq a$ or $a$.
- Since $(0,1,0,0,0,0,0)$ satisfies $\varphi$, each clause must contain either a negative litteral $\neq b$ or $b$.
- Since $S \neq \{0,1\}^7$, no clause can contain a variable and its negation.
- Since $(0,0,1,0,0,0,0)$ satisfies $\varphi$, there is no clause $(a\lor b)$ in $\varphi$ (and neither $a$ alone or $b$ alone).

Using the above properties, we conclude that each clause contains a positive litteral and a negative litteral.

But the last claim prove that $\mu = (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)$ satisfies $\varphi$. Since $\mu\notin S$, we conclude by contradiction that such a $\varphi$ cannot exist.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Ok, I understand everything from the assertion that every clause must contain a negative literal to the end.

But what I don't understand is why any literal in the potential instance can't contain ~a,~b, or ~c.

Comment: I don't understand your question. What does "a litteral can't contain ~a" mean?

Comment: In your second bullet point, you say that "each clause must contain either a negative literal $\neq a$", which means, that ~a can't be in any literal (I'm using ~ to mean NOT).

Comment: There is a **either** in this sentence, and I think you are sometimes confusing *clause* and *litteral*. In the second point, the litterals satisfied by $(1, 0, 0,0,0,0,0)$ are only $a$, $\neg b$, $\neg c$, …, $\neg g$, hence my comment.

Comment: Sorry, you're right: I meant "in any clause" instead of "in any literal". What I'm asking though is why can't there be, for example, $(\neg a \lor b)$, in $\varphi$?

Comment: Because the truth assignation $(1,0,0,0,0,0,0)$ that is in $S$ does not satisfy this clause.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the clarification.